# Why does the city of Minas Morgul glow green?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Why does the city of Minas Morgul glow green?

[image]

Please answer with quotes from original Tolkien stories and writings.

Comment: Why'd you delete this question? Seems like a perfectly valid question to me. Just because it's a duplicate doesn't mean that you have to delete it...

Comment: @Mithrandir I discovered it was a duplicate within a minute after posting it, so I deleted it. No need for duplicates. :-)